# Using LC oscillator to create square wave AC

Tags: transistors, inverter, passive-networks, square

A full wave bridge inverter lookslike this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8CIW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However this isn't practical because we have turn on/off the pairs of switches every time and it is not guaranteed that the rate we do this remains costant.

In the place of transistors we have electrical switches not mechanical switches called transistors.

The diagram looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3CWKa.png)</sup>

I have searched through the Internet and havent found a single project of a square wave inverter without a timer or a microproccessor turning the pairs of transistors on and off.

I was wondering if we could do it with an LC oscillator providing the frequency of turning on/off the transitors.

Let me show you what I mean.I will do it with 1 transistor to make it simplier to be understood.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqcOgZ.png)</sup>

In the tank circuit the electric field of the capacitor will become the magnetic field of the coil which will then again become the electric field of the capacitor.Every time this happens the direction of the electric field and the magnetic fields will change.

This can induce an alternating voltage to the loop with transistor turning it on and off every half cycle of oscillation.What do you think?

Comment: what is your question? since these mosfets are essentially voltage-controlled, of course you can control them with a voltage oscillator. You'll want to make sure that the transition from "completely off" to "completely on" is fast, or else you'll have half-on MOSFETs for a long duration, which will get very hot.

Comment: Just thinking if it could it possible.

Comment: Focus is the key word here. Anyone answering this knows how a H bridge works so all that early stuff is just wasting folk's time. Concentrate on the specific question and don't ask for opinions (off-topic).

Comment: It’s possible to drive the H bridge with an LC oscillator (with some buffer stage in between) but this would be inefficient for the MOSFETs and would heat up as Marcus mentions. H bridges are really meant to be driven by square wave or some form of pulse wave to be power efficient. If you wanted to convert a sine wave to square wave you can use a comparator for that.

Comment: There are plenty of PWM and H-bridge driver IC's in the market. Also, an LC circuit cannot sustain oscillation without a transistor to amplify feedback. No perpetual motion here, as slight DC resistance in the inductor will cause an LC oscillation to die out as a decaying ring-wave.

Answer (score 2):

> if it could it possible.

Yes. since these mosfets are essentially voltage-controlled, of course you can control them with a voltage oscillator.

You'll want to make sure that the transition from "completely off" to "completely on" is fast, or else you'll have half-on MOSFETs for a long duration, which will get very hot.

Your LC-Oscillator won't work like that (you need some way to get power in there, otherwise the thing will not oscillate), but I'm sure you can find enough oscillator circuits on wikipedia.

Comment: I assume the capacitor is precharged.

Comment: yeah, still not going to oscillate for long. Don't forget inductors, capacitors and wires aren't made of superconductors. Anyway, oscillators are really easy to research.

Answer (score 0):

M2 and M4 are easy to "drive", because their source pin is connected to the negative battery terminal. Thus, a positive gate voltage (with respect to source) on those two will "turn them on."

A problem comes with M1 and M3. Those are also N-channel enhancement-mode MOSFETs, just like M2 and M4. So to turn those on, they also need a positive gate voltage with respect to source. But what is the source pin connected to? What do their source pins "see" in terms of voltage during operation? That's right, it varies. So driving them properly requires either a floating supply, or other ingenious methods.

Now M1 and M3 could instead be P-channel MOSFETs and flipped upside-down, with their source tied to battery positive. Then they become "high-side switches" and pulling their gates low turns them on.

Another problem then creeps in: speed and matching. N-channel and P-channel devices are similar, but not identical in specifications.  So if you wired the gates of M1 and M2 together, then drove this with a big squarewave signal, there's a good chance that both will be "on" for some amount of time, which could destroy them. Timing is critical. Voltage is critical. Understanding the datasheet of the particular devices in question is critical.

To tackle all these problems, [gate driver IC's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_driver) were invented. These turn the gates on and off very fast, and ensure that only one can be "on" at all times.

So yes, while theoretically possible to switch MOSFETS from an oscillator, this generally is not done. It isn't precise enough for each MOSFET to ensure reliable operation.

Comment: The substrate and the gate are connected to the loop which gets current from the LC oscillator.

Comment: @HelenaWells your LC oscillator can't give anyone current. Afterwards, it would be drained of energy and can't oscillate

Comment: The LC oscillator while it is oscillating creates AC to the near loops.

Comment: yeah, but where do you think the energy you need to charge and discharge the MOSFETs' gates comes from? An LC oscillator is no mobile perpetuum, you need a power source.

Comment: The energy comes from the LC oscillator.

Answer (score 0):

Decades ago, I recall switching power supplies using tape_wound toroid transformers with:

- primary (center tapped, with push pull bipolar drivers, probably UNITRODE devices)
- secondary (or multiple secondaries, all slaved from the shared core flux)
- with feedback to each of the TWO bipolar power switches from TWO small_voltage_output secondaries.

I don't think "resonance" was part of the system design.

But instead of worrying about the need for Driver Electronics, think about using additional Secondary windings, and perhaps diode clipping to produce "square waves", and some parallel resistors with a diode in one of the paths to produce a useful imbalance in charge/discharge currents.